# SwishImplementation error when saving jit trace

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I am trying to jit trace and save my pytorch model from the segmentation models package. But I am getting an error. "Could not export Python function call 'SwishImplementation'. Remove calls to python functions before export. Did you forget to add @script or @scrript_method annotation? If this is a `nn.ModuleList`, add it to _ *constants* _"  It only happens when I use the efficientnet backbone. How can I get the `save()` function to work? I need to be able to use the model in a c++ application.

```
import torch
import segmentation_models_pytorch as smp

model = smp.Unet('efficientnet-b7')
model.eval()

input = torch.randn((1,3,224,224))
torch_out = model(input)

model = torch.jit.trace(model,input)
trace_out = model(input)

model.save('model.pt')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `UNET` model from the `segmentation_models_pytorch` module uses an `EfficientNet`, which uses a `MemoryEfficientSwish` module. To fix the error, change all instances of `MemoryEfficientSwish` to `Swish` before saving the model.

You can iterate through the `UNET` model, and if the module is an instance of `EfficientNet`, call the function `.set_swish(memory_efficient = False)`.

After that, you can load the `state_dict`, and then trace and save the model.